# why do we need to call take() for Option<T> variable

Tags: rust

In this piece of code:

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: String,
}

impl Post {
    pub fn new() -> Post {
        Post {
            state: Some(Box::new(Draft {})),
            content: String::new(),
        }
    }
    
    pub fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str) {
        self.content.push_str(text);
    }
    
    pub fn content(&self) -> &str {
        ""
    }

    pub fn request_review(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.take() {
            self.state = Some(s.request_review())
        }
    }
}

trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>; 
}

struct Draft {}

impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }
}

struct PendingReview {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        self
    }
}
```

there is a  call to `take()`; the book says:

> To consume the old state, the request_review method needs to take ownership of the state value. This is where the Option in the state field of Post comes in: we call the take method to take the Some value out of the state field and leave a None in its place.
>
> We need to set state to None temporarily rather than setting it directly with code like `self.state = self.state.request_review();` to get ownership of the state value. This ensures Post can’t use the old state value after we’ve transformed it into a new state.

How is it possible that `Post` uses its old state if we set it directly?

Comment: Whis is the meaning of "This ensures Post can’t use the old state value after we’ve transformed it into a new state." ?

Comment: Can we do this ?
```
self.state = Some( self.state.take().expect("abc").request_review());
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you code like this:

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Box<dyn State>,
    content: String,
}

trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>; 
}

impl Post {
    // ... 
    pub fn request_review(&mut self) {
        self.state = self.state.request_review();
    }
    // ... 
}
```

You will get a compiler error:

```
self.state = self.state.request_review();
             ^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.state` has type `std::boxed::Box<dyn State>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait'.
```

This is because calling `State::request_review` will move `Box<self>`, which is allocated on heap, and Rust doesn't allow you to just move values away from heap unless you implement `Copy`, otherwise what's left there?  The book uses `Option::take()` to move ownership out and leave `None` on the place.

Comment: Can we do this ?  self.state = Some( self.state.take().expect("abc").request_review());

Comment: Thanks for explaining it from a new angle. 

What is the meaning of "This ensures Post can’t use the old state value after we’ve transformed it into a new state." ?

Comment: pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: String,
}

It was Option<Box<.>>, not Box<.>.

Comment: How does "Rust doesn't allow you to just move values away from heap unless you implement Copy" make sense? I think this answer is missing a key piece of information. Quote from the book "we call the take method to take the Some value out of the state field and leave a None in its place, because Rust doesn’t let us have unpopulated fields in structs.". Looks like Rust does not detect move and assignment in same statement as valid.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the fact that the data is on the heap, as mentioned by @xiang-zhou, is the fundamental issue here. The following doesn't compile because the call to `Blog::request_review` tries to move the `state` field out of `self`:

```
impl Blog {
    pub fn request_review(&mut self) {
        self.state = self.state.request_review()
    }
}

impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }
}
```

However, this isn't permitted by the compiler because `self` and `self.state` are behind a reference. This would be a problem for data on the stack as well:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.state` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:23:22
   |
23 |         self.state = self.state.request_review()
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^ ---------------- `self.state` moved due to this method call
   |                      |
   |                      move occurs because `self.state` has type `Box<dyn State>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

To get around this, `Option::take` is used because it allows moving a value out from a `&mut` reference, something that is not usually allowed. The [source code for `Option::take`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b384692f4c7fa61b36f9314d6e597154914f4957/library/core/src/option.rs#L1620-L1626) and [`mem::replace`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5b08c9f39754039ef9c6cbde157ac9eb8c252a58/library/core/src/mem/mod.rs#L899-L913) rely on carefully implemented unsafe rust to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

If `request_review` panic, it will lead to free the `Box` twice, first in `request_review` and then when the `Option` is freed.

Comment: the book said it is possible that if we set the state directly Post might use old state value, I questioned how it is possible?

Comment: @Mohammadgorganmohammadi I don't get what you mean, could you point me where and in which book did you find this ?

Comment: We need to set state to None temporarily rather than setting it directly with code like self.state = self.state.request_review(); to get ownership of the state value. This ensures Post can’t use the old state value after we’ve transformed it into a new state.
page 501 rust official book:https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/

Comment: page link, https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html#requesting-a-review-of-the-post-changes-its-state

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the book; bold font my formatting

> we call the take method to take the Some value out of the state field
> and leave a None in its place, **because Rust doesn’t let us have
> unpopulated fields in structs**.

As for move and assignment in the same statement, looks like Rust does not detect it as valid.

Answer (score 0):

It's my personal opinion, but I think the example in Rust Book is nonsense.

If it were me implementing the same logic, it would be like:

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Box<dyn State>,
    content: String,
}

impl Post {
    pub fn new() -> Post {
        Post {
            state: Box::new(Draft {}),
            content: String::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn request_review(&mut self) {
        self.state = self.state.request_review();
    }
}

trait State {
    fn request_review(&self) -> Box<dyn State>; 
}

struct Draft {}

impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(&self) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }
}

struct PendingReview {}

impl State for PendingReview {
    fn request_review(&self) -> Box<dyn State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }
}
```

Without `Option` and `take()` at all.

The logic behind the implementation in The Book:

1. The reason why `state` needs to be an `Option` is that `request_review()` consumes the ownership.
2. The reason why `request_review()` consumes ownership is that `PendingState` returns `self`.
3. The reason why `PendingState#request_review()` return `self` is... to show that you can do it, as a teaching book, I guess. Or as a micro-optimization, just in case at a later point `PendingState` becomes a huge struct and it's expensive to allocate one.

If it just returns a new `Box::new(PendingReview{})` you don't need any of these complexity.

Comment: I think the reason why `request_review()` consumes ownership is to explicitly "invalidate" old state - compiler guarantees outdated state will not be used anywhere else.

Comment: My tinfoil hat conspiracy theory is that they wanted to make the State Design Pattern example unnecessarily complicated to show how good the type system in Rust really is. And in my case, it worked.