# cannot move out of a mutable reference Rust. error[E0507] from a leetcode problme (LinkedList for sure)

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust and trying to practice it with leetcode questions. Following are my code for [LC19. Remove Nth Node From End of List](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/description/).

```
// Definition for singly-linked list.
// #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
// pub struct ListNode {
//   pub val: i32,
//   pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
// }
// 
// impl ListNode {
//   #[inline]
//   fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
//     ListNode {
//       next: None,
//       val
//     }
//   }
// }

    pub fn remove_nth_from_end(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, n: i32) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        if head.is_none() {
            return head;
        }
        
        let mut dummy = Box::new(ListNode::new(0));
        dummy.next = head;

        let mut cur = dummy.clone();
        let mut prev = dummy.as_mut();
        
        for _ in 0..n {
            cur = cur.next.unwrap();
        }
        
        loop {
            match &cur.next {
                None => break,
                Some(_) => {
                    cur = cur.next.unwrap();
                    prev = prev
                            .next
                            .as_mut()
                            .unwrap();
                }
            }
        }

        // ---- Here is where the problem happened ----
        prev.next = prev
                        .next
                        .as_mut()
                        .unwrap()
                        .next;

        return dummy.next;

    }
```

The compiler complains about the following:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a mutable reference
  --> src/leetcode/lc00019/solution.rs:39:15
   |
39 |         prev.next = prev.next.as_mut().unwrap().next;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Option<Box<list_node::ListNode>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

It is confusing to me that the following code works but I could not understand why

```
        prev.next = prev
                        .next
                        .as_mut()
                        .unwrap() // -> &mut Box<ListNode>
                        .next     // -> Option<Box<ListNode>>
                        .take();  // -> Option<Box<ListNode>>
```

both `next` and `take()` gives the same type `Option<Box<ListNode>>` so why removing the `take()` failed to program ?

Any Rust expert can explain ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why do we need to call take() for Option<T> variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193489/why-do-we-need-to-call-take-for-optiont-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving a quick glance into what `take` does in the docs, we can understand a bit more of what is going on: [`Takes the value out of the option, leaving a None in its place.`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take).

While `prev.next = prev.next.as_mut().unwrap().next;` attempts to move the Option itself out of `prev`, leaving no value at all, `take` will use that mutable reference to move only what's *inside* the Option, swapping an `Option::Some` with an `Option::None`, but the Option itself remains.